# Microsoft Project Plan in xml format

Tags: xml, ms-project

Project Plan has functionality, that can convert `mpp` file into `xml`.

In the xml there are 4 main tags: *Calendars*, *Tasks*, *Resources*, *Assignments*

Is there any description or documentation how these tags are builded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-project/xml-data-interchange/introduction-to-project-xml-data?view=project-client-2016) are useful. But I will be appreciate for some better description

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow up MS project official web document as it is rich in supporting and guidance.
[MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/export-or-import-data-to-another-file-format-6e6e581f-a580-4f04-aa87-9b6552143d9c). The Export Wizard and Import Wizard help you transfer project data between Microsoft Project and other programs.